# Removing String array from ArrayList using an Iterator

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop, iterator

I'm trying to remove a given `String` array from an `ArrayList` using an `Iterator`. for a list of given apps. I'm using my class book as a resource for this, but I'm confused as to why I'm getting the error `cannot find symbol - method iterator();`. Should I be using an `Iterator` to remove a given `String` from my `ArrayList`? Or is there a better loop I should be using?

Thanks very much in advance.

```
    public void removeApp(String name)
{
    Iterator<App> it = name.iterator(); 
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        App app = it.next();
        String appName = app.getName();
        if (appName.equals(name)) {
            it.remove();
            System.out.println(appName + "has been removed.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Can't find app. Please try again.");
}
```

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava That seems to be an entirely different problem than this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be using an Iterator to remove a given String from my
>   ArrayList? Or is there a better loop I should be using?

for/foreach loop on Iterable (which ArrayList is an implementation) are not designed to remove elements during iteration. Your approach with Iterator is the correct one.

You can do in this way :

```
List<App> list = ...;
for(Iterator<App> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    App app = it.next();
    String appName = app.getName();
    if (appName.equals(name)) {
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(appName + "has been removed.");
    }
}
```

Or as alternative you can use `List.removeIf()` such as :

```
List<App> list = ...;
list.removeIf(app -> app.getName().equals(name));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the parameter `name` is a string and you can call `.iterator()` only on objects, that implement `Iterable`:

```
name.iterator(); // here is the error
```

Please, refer to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) for more details (and implementations).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `.iterator()` on your name parameter, instead of on a List of Apps.

Also, you should `return` just after you delete the App (after `it.remove(); System.out.println(appName + "has been removed.");`) otherwise you will always print "Can't find app. Please try again." (unless you can have various App objects with same names).